# How could a List contains different types in java?

Tags: java, generics

I am learning Java Generics and wildcards, knowing that for a List<>, we always allow only one type across all the elements it contains. However, when I write the code this way (maybe known as producer-extend and consumer-super?), multiple types are allowed to exist in the list I created!

Did I misunderstand something about the term `type safe`? Actually, I found it really confusing why I have to do the `producer-extend and consumer-super`.

```
public static void wildcard(List<? super Integer> list) {
        list.add(1); 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("String");
        wildcard(list);

        System.out.println(list);
    }
```

> [String, 1]

Comment: There is just one type of thing in your list, `Object`s. `Object` is the ancestor of all types in Java, so there's nothing wrong with this. A `String` is an `Object`. Similarly, an `Integer`is an `Object`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, there's nothing special about that.  You have a `List<Object>`.  You can write

```
Object a = "String";
Object b = 1;
```

...demonstrating an `Object` can be a `String` or an `Integer`, just like a `List` can be an `ArrayList` or a `LinkedList`.  A `List<Object>` can hold all kinds of objects.  Using a `List<Object>` is essentially telling the compiler that this can contain any kind of object, and you're willing to accept the associated type safety issues.

Answer (score -3):

No you don't misunderstand.

All the type safety is removed at runtime by a process called type erasure. So any list can store anything inherited from Java.lang.object.

Generics allow a measured amount of type safety. ? allows a sort of half-way house.

Comment: That's missing the point. Even in C#, where type erasure doesn't happen, a `List<object>` can still hold both strings and integers, because strings and integers are both objects.

Comment: Huh?  This has nothing to do with type erasure, it's just the type system's normal interaction with the type `Object`.

Comment: I don't think this answer deserves this amount of downvotes. Sure he missed the point but it actually has to do with the part related to the bounded wildcard.